# MVC 5 Razor View - Loading Partial views in foreach loop with the need to have show/hide toggle set to each partial

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, view, asp.net-mvc-partialview

**Added Section:** 
Simple Version: I'm on PersonView
It has a Drop down for How Many Phone Numbers do you have: ___
Drop down options are 1=5.

User selects 3.

Action Item 1: I need to add 3 partial views to this view that I'm on from a foreach loop.

Concern on Item 1: The partial views being added have a hidden div that is connected to a show/hide function.

How can the views be added after item selected and named so a hide/show will know which on is which.

**Details:**

I need to load partial views in a foreach loop, and not sure how to set the content of the partial dynamically so show/hide jquery can be set to each item as needed.

Issue: The Partial view has a div with an id that has a jquery function set to hide/show based on radio button selection.

Example working example on a 1 partial to 1 jquery is this: (This all works fine)

```
<div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-8 col-md-8">
        @Html.LabelFor(l => l.HasPhone)
        <label> @Html.RadioButtonFor(r => r.HasPhone, true, new { @class = "ui-controlgroup-item", id = "yeshasphone" }) Yes</label>
        <label> @Html.RadioButtonFor(r => r.HasPhone, false, new { @class = "ui-controlgroup-item", id = "nohasphone" }) No</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="collapse panel-default" id="hasphonedata">
</div>
```

This has a JQuery Hide/Show toggle set to it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('input:radio[name="HasPhone"]').click(function () {
    var value = $("#yeshasphone").is(':checked');
    if (value) {
        $("#hasphonedata").show();
    } else {
        $("#hasphonedata").hide();
    }
});
```

**How can I load the partial views from a loop in a way to have that item be set to a specific name that I can wire the jquery toggler to:**

My Loop to load from foreach:

```
@{
    foreach (PersonViewModel person in Model)
    {
        @Html.Partial("/Edit/_IndividualEdit", child)       
        <div class="hidden-display" id="@person.HasPhone">
            @Html.Partial("/Edit/_AliasPersonEdit", child)
        </div>
    }
}
```

**Question is:** How can I load 3 partial views that have hidden div set to jquery show hide function, and name those 3 partials so they are all different names match-able to a new jquery function to work for those 3 functions?

Comment: Can you please brief your problem. like what is your requirement. As code given doesn't give a clear picture.

Comment: @KushalSeth - I added a simple scenario on top. Thanks